# IBM TS 3310 upgrade firmware

Tags: ibm, service, tape, firmware, library

Am I allowed to upgrade firmware (by self)  for tape library IBM TS 3310 which service support contract has been finished?

Answer (score 0):

I can't see why not - firmware updates should be freely available for download

But if you go to IBM you must have a contract. Doesn't make any sense but it works that way.